# Android Espresso typeText into EditText in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-espresso

I have a `SearchView` in my ActionBar that is inflated from XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_bar_search_icon"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

I inflate it in my Fragment this way:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_menu_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

And my test:

```
onView(withId(R.id.catalog_filter_indicator_header_text)).perform(click());

//enter text and wait for suggestions
onView(withId(R.id.action_menu_search)).perform(click());
onViewisAssignableFrom(AutoCompleteTextView.class)).perform(click(), typeText("test"));
```

It looks like that field looses focus when it starts typing. And I don't know why.

All views are found and `typeText` statement passes without a hitch, but text does not appear in the field. I also tried that with simple `EditText` and custom `android:actionLayout` but with the same results.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I decided to create my own custom action because I wasn't be able to typeText work. Here you are my code:

```
public static ViewAction setText(final String text){
    return new ViewAction(){
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(TextView.class));
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Change view text";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            ((TextView) view).setText(text);
        }
    };
}
```

This code is useful to write code in all children from TextView. F. ex, EditText.

I took this code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850190/1360815

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use [`UiController.injectKeyEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/UiController.html#injectKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)) in order to more closely simulate actual typing?

Answer (score 20):

This code works for the `SerachView` in my `ActionBar`, as the `SearchView` is the only `EditText` in my `Fragment` :

```
onView(withId(R.id.action_search)).perform(click());    
onView(isAssignableFrom(EditText.class)).perform(typeText("test"), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
```

`KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` is the code for pressing the submit button.

Comment: My code does the same thing as yours. Do you run your tests on emulator or genymotion or actual devices?

Comment: Did you try it with EditTex instead of AutoCompleteTextView. I think I have tried it with AutoCompleteTextView before and that didn't work for me... My tests are running on actual devices and emulator.

Comment: `pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)` does the same thing and is a bit more readable IMO.

Comment: if you want a more specific class because you have more EditTexts in your screen you can use SearchView.SearchAutoComplete.class

Answer (score 12):

Search view has default id.
You can get it in Espresso in this way.

```
onView(withId(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("example"), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
```

Prior to AndroidX, the ID was `android.support.design.R.id.search_src_text`

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 2):

The id of the EditText in SearchView is `search_src_text`

```
onView(withId(R.id.action_menu_search)).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("test"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is good but it is not necessary anymore since the official Espresso library included the same functionality with `replaceText` function.

You can use it like below without a custom implementation

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_src_text)).perform(replaceText("test"))
```