# Android testing. How to change text of a TextView using Espresso

Tags: android, testing, textview, android-espresso, android-testing

It is easy to update an `EditText` with **Espresso**, but I can not find a way to change a text (like with a `TextView.setText("someText");` method) during the testing process.

```java
ViewAction.replaceText(stringToBeSet);
```

Is not working, cos it should be an `EditText`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can look into implementing your own ViewAction.

Here is the modified version of the replaceText viewaction from espresso library that is meant to work on the `TextView`.

```
 public static ViewAction setTextInTextView(final String value){
            return new ViewAction() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                    return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(TextView.class));
                }

                @Override
                public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                    ((TextView) view).setText(value);
                }

                @Override
                public String getDescription() {
                    return "replace text";
                }
            };
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I will like couple more your responses ))

Comment: Thanks you guy, you help me with typeText issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin** version of the @Be_Negative awesome answer,

Since there is no default `ViewAction` for setting text on `TextView` in Espresso,  you have to create your own.

**Step 1:** Define a new ViewAction to set text on `TextView` such as,

```
fun setTextInTextView(value: String): ViewAction {
    return object : ViewAction {
        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return CoreMatchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed(), ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(TextView::class.java))
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
            (view as TextView).text = value
        }

        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "replace text"
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it as,

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_text_view)).perform(setTextInTextView("Espresso is awesome"))
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can simply add your layout TextView in your layout that you have declared***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#123456"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

### Write code in your test

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mMain = new ActivityTestRule<> (MainActivity.class);

   /*set text view in textView */

            public static ViewAction setTextInTextView(final String value){
                return new ViewAction() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                        return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(TextView.class));
        //                                        
        // To check that the found view is TextView or it's subclass like EditText
        // so it will work for TextView and it's descendants
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                        ((TextView) view).setText(value);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getDescription() {
                        return "replace text";
                    }
                };
            }
```

**Now your method like that**

```
          //need add your test case here
            @Test
            public void showTextView(){

                delay(2000);
                onView(withId(R.id.editText))
                        .perform(setTextInTextView("my text"));
                delay(2000);
            }
```

**Now you can also add delay method to show also emulator or real device*

```
    /* delay checking of this position */
    private void delay(long i) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(i);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your layout TextView in your layout that you have declared

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#123456"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

** Write code in test class to check text is displaying on textview**

```
 @Test
public void checkUserId(){
    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
}
```