# How to set a value to the textview using Espresso in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, textview, android-espresso

I am writing the test cases for the Fragment. I can able to set a text to the Edittext but am unable to setText to the text view from testing. Please, anyone, help me to resolve this issue.Bellow is my code for edit text.

```
   onView(withId(R.id.editText))
        .perform(typeText("my text"), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

Please help me how to set a text to the text view.

Answer (score 6):

It's happening due to the precondition of [typeText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#typeText(java.lang.String)typeText) i.e.

> View preconditions:
>
> must be displayed on screen
>
> **must support input methods**

[Input method](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) is not supported by `TextView`(user cannot input values into it via keyboard or something else) so hence the issue

Solution : you can implement your own view `ViewAction`

[From how to create View action to set text on TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850190/4936904)

```
public static ViewAction setTextInTextView(final String value){
            return new ViewAction() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                    return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(TextView.class));
//                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
// To check that the found view is TextView or it's subclass like EditText
// so it will work for TextView and it's descendants  
                }

                @Override
                public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                    ((TextView) view).setText(value);
                }

                @Override
                public String getDescription() {
                    return "replace text";
                }
            };
    }
```

then you can do

```
onView(withId(R.id.editText))
        .perform(setTextInTextView("my text"));
```

Comment: what is this in that view Action allOf,isAssignableFrom

Comment: it is for type safety . i.e. the found view should be subtype of textview , it's sort of like a instanceof check

Comment: is both methods can import

Comment: iam unable to imprt that methods

Comment: try adding `import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom;`

Comment: what library you used for that

Comment: it's inside [support espresso](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158661/discussion-between-gowthami-and-pavneet-singh).

Comment: @gowthami i am glad that i could help