# android expresso testing fail calling onview twice

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-espresso

I'm testinig code I've written for android, I'm using JUnit4 and `android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.*`.
It happens if I call twice `onview` on a previous called android object like an `EditText`, `TexView`, `Button` or else, I get an exception, I don't know if I'm missing something or it is a bug, how to fix that?

```
onView(withId(R.id.name))
        .perform(typeText(NAME), closeSoftKeyboard());
onView(withId(R.id.surname))
        .perform(typeText(SURNAME), closeSoftKeyboard());
onView(withId(R.id.name))
        .perform(replaceText(NAME), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

Error log:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'replace text' on view 'with id: com.myapp:id/name'.
    at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformExceptio 
 n.java:84)

    at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:81)
    at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:52)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:167)
    at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:110)
    at com...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(is displayed on the screen to the user and is assignable from class: class android.widget.EditText)
```

Layout xml:

```
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="9">
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nomeLabel" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/surnameLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cognomeLabelVal" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/surname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:onClick="save"
            android:text="@string/saveName" />
    </GridLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you add code of  layout containing `name` and `surname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the log the view `name` is not assignable from `EditText`. See documentation of [ViewActions.replaceText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#replaceText(java.lang.String))

You need to write your own `ViewAction` for this. 
From another post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846738/android-testing-espresso-change-text-in-a-textview/32850190#32850190) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216782/how-to-set-a-value-to-the-textview-using-espresso-in-android) 
Create your own `ViewAction` like below.

```
public static ViewAction setTextInTextView(final String value){
    return new ViewAction() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(TextView.class));
            //                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            // To check that the found view is TextView or it's subclass like EditText
            // so it will work for TextView and it's descendants
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            ((TextView) view).setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "replace text";
        }
    };
}
```

Then Replace your code like this

```
 onView(withId(R.id.name))
            .perform(setTextInTextView(NAME), closeSoftKeyboard());
 onView(withId(R.id.surname))
            .perform(setTextInTextView(SURNAME), closeSoftKeyboard());
 onView(withId(R.id.name))
            .perform(setTextInTextView(NAME), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

Comment: It works but if performs click          <onView(withId(R.id.save)).perform(click())> get an exception.
"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user."

Comment: there is no save button in layout you posted. Can you update the layout?