# Test text submit on SearchView when using Espresso

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, searchview, android-junit

How can I submit some text to `SearchView` in *androidTest*?

`onView(withId(R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("text"))` doesn't work for me - app crashes at this line

```
@Test
fun testSearchViewTextSubmit() {
    ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)

    onView(withId(R.id.search_action)).perform(click()) // ok 

    onView(withId(R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("text")) // failed
}
```

> androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy
>   found matching: with id: com.example.test:id/search_src_text

Answer (score 0):

@LorenzoCamaione answer was success when I tried with my application.

```
        onView(withId(android.support.design.R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("example"), pressKey(
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
```

[Lorenzo answer in other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927365/android-espresso-typetext-into-edittext-in-actionbar)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Resource#getSystem to get the View

```
Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("search_src_text",
    "id", "android")


onView(withId(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("search_src_text",
"id", "android"))).perform(clearText(),typeText("enter the text"))
.perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
```